# Druid query in Power BI shows errors

Tags: powerbi, m, druid

I've got a problem connecting my report with a Druid database, based on a query that runs perfectly in Postman.

So the original Druid query is this:

```
curl -L -X POST 'https://api.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxx' --data-raw '{ "query":{
"metrics": [
    {
        "type": "count",
        "filter": {
            "type": "and",
            "children": [
                {
                    "type": "eq",
                    "field": "event.type",
                    "value": "check-point"
                },
                {
                    "type": "eq",
                    "field": "check_point.name",
                    "value": "Start of article"
                }
            ]
        },
        "values": {
            "main": "value"
        },
        "name": "Początek strony artykułowej",
        "clicked": false,
        "id": 2,
        "enabled": true
    },
    {
        "type": "count",
        "filter": {
            "type": "and",
            "children": [
                {
                    "type": "eq",
                    "field": "event.type",
                    "value": "check-point"
                },
                {
                    "type": "eq",
                    "field": "check_point.name",
                    "value": "Start of article content"
                }
            ]
        },
        "values": {
            "main": "value"
        },
        "name": "Początek treści",
        "clicked": false,
        "id": 3,
        "enabled": true
    },
    {
        "type": "count",
        "filter": {
            "type": "and",
            "children": [
                {
                    "type": "eq",
                    "field": "event.type",
                    "value": "check-point"
                },
                {
                    "type": "eq",
                    "field": "check_point.name",
                    "value": "Start of article lead"
                }
            ]
        },
        "values": {
            "main": "value"
        },
        "name": "Początek leadu",
        "clicked": false,
        "id": 4,
        "enabled": true
    },
    {
        "type": "count",
        "filter": {
            "type": "and",
            "children": [
                {
                    "type": "eq",
                    "field": "event.type",
                    "value": "check-point"
                },
                {
                    "type": "eq",
                    "field": "check_point.name",
                    "value": "Start of article text"
                }
            ]
        },
        "values": {
            "main": "value"
        },
        "name": "Początek tekstu",
        "clicked": false,
        "id": 6,
        "enabled": true
    },
    {
        "type": "count",
        "filter": {
            "type": "and",
            "children": [
                {
                    "type": "eq",
                    "field": "event.type",
                    "value": "check-point"
                },
                {
                    "type": "eq",
                    "field": "check_point.name",
                    "value": "End of article"
                }
            ]
        },
        "values": {
            "main": "value"
        },
        "name": "Koniec tekstu",
        "clicked": false,
        "id": 13,
        "enabled": true
    }
],
"from": "TvH38YhQ0u5d",
"top": 10,
"granularity": "all",
"realtime": false,
"intervals": {
    "dates": [
        "2022-06-03T00:00:00.000",
        "2022-06-04T00:00:00.000"
    ],
    "translatedFrom": "2022-06-03T00:00:00+02:00/2022-06-03T23:59:59+02:00",
    "strict": true
},
"timeZoneOffset": -120,
"dashboard": {
    "_id": "62e0e9e3d65b2200087afe93",
    "name": "{OS} Kontrolne",
    "type": "default",
    "organizationId": "5c666b78c66c847f427326e0",
    "createdAt": "2022-07-27T07:31:47.723Z",
    "owner": "myemail@mycompany.com",
    "__v": 0,
    "privilege": "edit",
    "dashboardId": "62e0e9e3d65b2200087afe93"
},
"offset": 0,
"splits": [
    {
        "name": "ID",
        "field": "mycustomvalue.article.id",
        "regex": "",
        "id": 10
    }
],
"order": [
    {
        "metricIndex": 0,
        "ascending": false
    }
],
"filters": {
    "type": "and",
    "children": [
        {
            "type": "eq",
            "field": "event.type",
            "value": "check-point"
        },
        {
            "type": "eq",
            "field": "page.domain",
            "value": "mycustomvalue.pl"
        },
        {
            "type": "eq",
            "field": "user.device.crawler.miscellaneous.iscrawler",
            "value": "false"
        },
        {
            "type": "gt",
            "field": "source.mycustomvalue.article.id",
            "value": "0"
        }
    ]
}}}'
```

And this works in Postman.

However when I try to rewrite it to M, I am getting errors (most often "invalid identifier" after "query".

```
let 

RequestBody =Json.Document(Text.ToBinary("{" ""query"":{
    ""metrics"": [
        {
            ""type"": ""count"",
            ""filter"": {
                ""type"": ""and"",
                ""children"": [
                    {
                        ""type"": ""eq"",
                        ""field"": ""event.type"",
                        ""value"": ""check-point""
                    },
                    {
                        ""type"": ""eq"",
                        ""field"": ""check_point.name"",
                        ""value"": ""Start of article""
                    }
                ]
            },
            ""values"": {
                ""main"": ""value""
            },
            ""name"": ""Początek strony artykułowej"",
            ""clicked"": false,
            ""id"": 2,
            ""enabled"": true
        },
        {
            ""type"": ""count"",
            ""filter"": {
                ""type"": ""and"",
                ""children"": [
                    {
                        ""type"": ""eq"",
                        ""field"": ""event.type"",
                        ""value"": ""check-point""
                    },
                    {
                        ""type"": ""eq"",
                        ""field"": ""check_point.name"",
                        ""value"": ""Start of article content""
                    }
                ]
            },
            ""values"": {
                ""main"": ""value""
            },
            ""name"": ""Początek treści"",
            ""clicked"": false,
            ""id"": 3,
            ""enabled"": true
        },
        {
            ""type"": ""count"",
            ""filter"": {
                ""type"": ""and"",
                ""children"": [
                    {
                        ""type"": ""eq"",
                        ""field"": ""event.type"",
                        ""value"": ""check-point""
                    },
                    {
                        ""type"": ""eq"",
                        ""field"": ""check_point.name"",
                        ""value"": ""Start of article lead""
                    }
                ]
            },
            ""values"": {
                ""main"": ""value""
            },
            ""name"": ""Początek leadu"",
            ""clicked"": false,
            ""id"": 4,
            ""enabled"": true
        },
        {
            ""type"": ""count"",
            ""filter"": {
                ""type"": ""and"",
                ""children"": [
                    {
                        ""type"": ""eq"",
                        ""field"": ""event.type"",
                        ""value"": ""check-point""
                    },
                    {
                        ""type"": ""eq"",
                        ""field"": ""check_point.name"",
                        ""value"": ""Start of article text""
                    }
                ]
            },
            ""values"": {
                ""main"": ""value""
            },
            ""name"": ""Początek tekstu"",
            ""clicked"": false,
            ""id"": 6,
            ""enabled"": true
        },
        {
            ""type"": ""count"",
            ""filter"": {
                ""type"": ""and"",
                ""children"": [
                    {
                        ""type"": ""eq"",
                        ""field"": ""event.type"",
                        ""value"": ""check-point""
                    },
                    {
                        ""type"": ""eq"",
                        ""field"": ""check_point.name"",
                        ""value"": ""End of article""
                    }
                ]
            },
            ""values"": {
                ""main"": ""value""
            },
            ""name"": ""Koniec tekstu"",
            ""clicked"": false,
            ""id"": 13,
            ""enabled"": true
        }
    ],
    ""from"": ""TvH38YhQ0u5d"",
    ""top"": 10,
    ""granularity"": ""all"",
    ""realtime"": false,
    ""intervals"": {
        ""dates"": [
            ""2022-06-03T00:00:00.000"",
            ""2022-06-04T00:00:00.000""
        ],
        ""translatedFrom"": ""2022-06-03T00:00:00+02:00/2022-06-03T23:59:59+02:00"",
        ""strict"": true
    },
    ""timeZoneOffset"": -120,
    ""dashboard"": {
        ""_id"": ""62e0e9e3d65b2200087afe93"",
        ""name"": ""{OS} Kontrolne"",
        ""type"": ""default"",
        ""organizationId"": ""5c666b78c66c847f427326e0"",
        ""createdAt"": ""2022-07-27T07:31:47.723Z"",
        ""owner"": ""myemail@mycompany.com"",
        ""__v"": 0,
        ""privilege"": ""edit"",
        ""dashboardId"": ""62e0e9e3d65b2200087afe93""
    },
    ""offset"": 0,
    ""splits"": [
        {
            ""name"": ""ID"",
            ""field"": ""mycustomvalue.article.id"",
            ""regex"": """",
            ""id"": 10
        }
    ],
    ""order"": [
        {
            ""metricIndex"": 0,
            ""ascending"": false
        }
    ],
    ""filters"": {
        ""type"": ""and"",
        ""children"": [
            {
                ""type"": ""eq"",
                ""field"": ""event.type"",
                ""value"": ""check-point""
            },
            {
                ""type"": ""eq"",
                ""field"": ""page.domain"",
                ""value"": ""mycustomvalue.pl""
            },
            {
                ""type"": ""eq"",
                ""field"": ""user.device.crawler.miscellaneous.iscrawler"",
                ""value"": ""false""
            },
            {
                ""type"": ""gt"",
                ""field"": ""source.mycustomvalue.article.id"",
                ""value"": ""0""
            }
        ]
    }
} "}")]))),
Source = Web.Contents("https://api.xxxxxxxxxx&Authorization=Bearer xxxxxxxxxx&Content-Type=application/json", [Content = Json.FromValue(RequestBody)])

in 

Source
```

I tried many combinations in M, however any attempt to connect with this query is rejected. Did anyone have such a problem with Druid? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are the headers appended to the Uri?  They are supposed to go in the options.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/web-contents

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft well, this is one of my attempts, so it may be wrong. But with headers in options it still doesn't work.

Comment: Thats disappointing. I was expecting a druid query to have something to do with nature and trees

Answer (score 1):

> However when I try to rewrite it to M, I am getting errors (most often
> "invalid identifier" after "query".

It seems like you have a couple of extra " characters, looking at the first

> let
>
> RequestBody =Json.Document(Text.ToBinary("{" ""query"":{

and last

> } "}")]))),

lines of your query. I think the extra quote is causing the early termination to your string.

This is how those lines should probably look:

```
let 

RequestBody =Json.Document(Text.ToBinary("{ ""query"":{
```

and

```
} }")]))),
```